# showing $y\to |y|^{p}$ is convex $p\geq 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

$y\to |y|^{p}$ is convex only for $p\geq 1$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

This function is nondifferentiable but we can see that the second derivative is nonnegative in each interval $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$. So each wing is convex.

Can I use this to prove convexity for the original function? If not can you give a hint?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is convex on both wings of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I know that. The question is if it follows directly for the original function.

Comment: yes but it has to be differentiable. This function is not.

Comment: dude, use the tick button to accept answers... i noticed you never accepted anything...

Answer (score 0):

for $x,y>0$, or  $x,y<0$, there are no problems. If one of them is 0, there is also no problem.

Only problem is if $x<y<0$

Consider the functions

$f(x) = |x|^p$ for $x<0$, $0$ otherwise.

$g(x) = x^p$ for $x>0$, $0$ otherwise.

then $f$ and $g$ are convex (why? this is easy from definitions), maximum of two convex is convex. (why? prove this)

Comment: @TKM this is a hw question for a functional analysis course i am going. i did it just now after seeing your post, so good exercise for me too... max of two functions somehow feels like cheating, but i am too lazy to get an inequality for a direct proof